<IPython.core.display.Markdown object> instead of the actual Markdown text
I am running the following code:
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
display(Markdown('<b>Hello</b>'))

I get <IPython.core.display.Markdown object> instead of the bolded text.
I tried to print() it, or trying to make the the text to a string using str(), but it would not display the bold text. Instead, it displays <IPython.core.display.Markdown object>.

This question is similar to: How to display <IPython.core.display.HTML object>?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
